# In my model, I've got a piece of information that can be shown in two different ways. If I create two fields for both ways, how can I link the two?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a list of tasks that have both a numerical code and a name. For example:

```
100 - "Sweep floor"
200 - "Do laundry"
300 - "Walk the dogs"
```

In my model, I'd like to have something like the following:

```
public class Task
{
    public int TaskID { get; set; }
    public int TaskNumber { get; set; }
    public string TaskName { get; set; }
}
```

When creating a `Task`, if the user selects "100" for the `TaskNumber`, I'd like the `TaskName` to change to "Sweep floor". Vice versa, if a user selects the `TaskName` "Sweep floor", I'd like the `TaskNumber` to change to "100".

The purpose of having them separate is in case a user only knows the name or only knows the number of a task. The fields would be sorted numerically and alphabetically so they could quickly find the task they're looking for.

I understand that one solution to this is to simply create a JavaScript function that watches both the fields. When one of the field changes, the other changes to match it.

Is there a better solution than that? I'd rather make something like an`Enum` for `TaskNumber` and `TaskName` and have them be linked somehow instead of hardcoding a solution in JavaScript.

Comment: Why not use an single autocomplete control - typing "10" or "Sw" would show "100 - Sweep floor" in the list

Comment: That sounds much more sensible. Is there something in particular I need to implement? I already have an `enum` dropdown list in another model, but it doesn't let me type to filter possible selections

Comment: You could use a [jquery-ui autocomplete](https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/) for example (attach it to textbox, and when x number of characters are called, make an ajax call to get a list of matches (i.e. `TaskNumber` or `TaskName` contains the text) - the  server method would return a collection of the `TaskID` and the 'joined'  `TaskNumber` or `TaskName` values. When a user selects an item from the list, you assign the associated `TaskID` to a hidden input that is bound to your model property for the selected task